# background-image shows correctly on desktop browsers, not shown on mobile browsers

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I have a system based on jquery mobile. I added a symbol on the search text box which resets the search text box value.

```
.ui-input-search .ui-icon-delete {
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-image: url(images/close-disable.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 90000;
}
```

I checked through Chrome inspect tool on the mobile (network tab), and the image is loaded.

When accessing through the desktop, its showing correctly. Only on mobile it doesn't work (I tried on multiple browsers, doesn't work on any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find an answer. For some reason, on mobile, you need to add background-size: 100%;

Answer (score 2):

It may be a conflict caused by the input using the OS's native display setup for the control, try explicitly setting the `appearance` property to `none` ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance))

```
.ui-input-search .ui-icon-delete {
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-image: url(images/close-disable.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 90000;
    -moz-appearace:none;
    -webkit-appearace:none;
    appearace:none;
}
```

Alternatively, try:

```
background-image: url(images/close-disable.png)!important;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
..ui-input-search .ui-icon-delete{
  background: url("../assets/lotus.png") no-repeat center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Use background-size 100% 100% to adjust full screen width height in mobile

Answer (score 1):

For me workes this:

```
.ui-input-search .ui-icon-delete { 
   background-image: url(images/close-disable.png)!important;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and I noticed that it was just a file permission problem. I corrected this by accessing my server via FTP, right click on the image file, going to "file permission" option and setting the "777" permission :D